# passing "&" string to controller using get method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass string via url GET parameters to my MVC controller. But the problem is whenever inside my string any "&" comes up its just getting skipped the text from there. The reason i found is on http get "&" is reserved for define new parameters. Is there any way to pass string smoothly?

> http://localhost:60617/CategoryResearch/Result?page=1&keywords=Baby
>   Safety & Health
>
> Example string is: "Baby Safety & Health"

Comment: You need to send URL encoded value of & in the query string

Comment: any example? @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: use HttpUtility.UrlEncode to fix this.

Comment: https://www.urlencoder.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to UrlEncode your string before sending it. Take a look at [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
string keyWords = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Baby Safety & Health");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to send the & encoded as this:

http://localhost:60617/CategoryResearch/Result?page=1&keywords=Baby Safety %26 Health

Here you have a complete reference on how to encode special characters:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 1):

Ampersand's are one of many characters that have a special meaning when your browser parses a URL. You can learn more about this from the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

In order to use these characters in a URL, the URL must be encoded. In C#, you can use [UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate an encoded URL string.

Answer (score -2):

Yes; that's correct.
You need to use JSON.stringify while placing the parameters. It will encode "&" and other special characters. For example,

```
data: {
            emp_id: JSON.stringify(emp_id)              
      },
```

Comment: URL encoding is not the same as JSON encoding.